# Mapbender: failed to load WMS-layer / target elements not defined

Tags: wms, ogc, mapbender

After creating a WMS (1.3.0) in GeoServer (2.15.1) I cannot load the WMS service in Mapbender (v. 3.0.8.1).
Original WMS-URL:

```
http://localhost:8082/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
```

In GeoServer all of the layers are displayed correctly. The WMS layers can also be loaded properly in QGIS (WMS layer).
For the app configuration I have followed the instructions from the [Mapbender documentation](https://doc.mapbender.org/en/quickstart.html). Independently on the chosen source in the layersets of the app the WMS cannot be loaded. I also get the errors: **"element: a target element is not defined"** although I have defined those elements:
[image]

I also tried to choose other sources which are already available from the source list in Mapbender but got the same errors. I am running both GeoServer and Mapbender on the OsGeoLive13 virtual machine (virtual box).

Can someone tell me why the WMS layers cannot be loaded or why do I see just an empty screen?

I simply cannot load any WMS layer in Mapbender but have followed all steps in Mapbender documentation. A problem with the GetCapabilities document could be the clue.

Comment: Not that it is usually a problem, but to be aware that parameter values are case sensitive, and the specification says it should be `service="WMS"`

Comment: Usually when giving the URL of a service to client software that will generate requests you provide just the end point of the service, so just ` http://localhost:8082/geoserver/ows?` in this case.  then the client will add the request parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mapbender layout edit dialog, the layersets source needs to be defined. The layout elements incl. WMS will then be displayed correctly in the app.

Comment: You should accept your own answer